# Task Complete Emails - Making it easier

Tags: 2007

I'm currently using Sharepoint 2007 Basic and an add-in for Project called Project Publisher.

Basically, it uploads a Project file as a List and synchronises back and forth with Sharepoint and Project, so when a user updates a task as complete, it pulls the information back down in to a central plan.

At the current time, we have to use a Datasheet view so that it's easy for users to update when their tasks are complete (ie without having to open the task, as apparently that's too much work for them!)

Is there a way (without using SP Designer) that I can create a Task Complete style button over the task in Sharepoint, which will automatically mark the task as complete, generate an email to a mailing list and will hopefully avoid us having to use the datasheet view.

Hopefully you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been setting it to send emails when the task status was set to "Complete" not "Completed" which Sharepoint runs off - idiot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but take a look at CodePlex project [Bulk Actions for SharePoint](http://spbulkactions.codeplex.com/). It seems to do 90% of what you need, you will probably need to add custom email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment uses a normal SharePoint Task List, you can synchronise this with Outlook, and marking as "Complete" is as simple as clearing the red flag within outlook.

You can tell if it is a standard Task List as from within the list in SharePoint, under the ACtions menu you may see a link to "Connect to Outlook".

If not, then you would probably have to code a solution in Visual Studio for this.